# Activate Select Element Safari - AppleScript

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I am new to `AppleScript` and I am trying to figure out how to active a selected element.

My pathetic attempt to have safari activate target element:

[image: My pathetic attempt to have safari activate target element]

I select the element by tabbing to it. Active Element is Play Button:

[image: Active Element is Play Button].

Yet when I try to run script, I get the following error:

[image: get the following error].

Could anyone please inform me of my error and/or show an example of a workaround?

Comment: What is the actual URL of the screen shot of the https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gVCk.png image?

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript in your AppleScript code, you can click the play/ pause button on a YouTube video in Safari with this following code in Script Editor app

```
clickYouTubePlayButton("ytp-play-button ytp-button", 0)

to clickYouTubePlayButton(theClassName, elementnum)
    if application "Safari" is running then
        try
            tell application "Safari"
                tell window 1 to set current tab to tab 1 whose URL contains "youtube"
                do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')[" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
            end tell
        end try
    end if
end clickYouTubePlayButton
```

---

[image]

---

In response to the comment from user @user3439894, in regard to having to enable Safari to allow JavaScript events, for the above code to work...  This following code will automate the process of enabling the JavaScript events in Safari if need be..

Tested using the latest version of macOS Mojave and the latest version of Safari

```
global windowName, errMsg, errNum

clickYouTubePlayButton("ytp-play-button ytp-button", 0)

to clickYouTubePlayButton(theClassName, elementnum)
    if application "Safari" is running then
        try
            tell application "Safari"
                tell window 1 to set current tab to tab 1 whose URL contains "youtube"
                do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('" & theClassName & "')
                [" & elementnum & "].click();" in document 1
            end tell
        on error errMsg number errNum
            if errNum is 8 then
                my enableJavascript()
            end if
        end try
    end if
end clickYouTubePlayButton

on enableJavascript()
    tell application "Safari" to activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Safari"
            click menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            click menu item 4 of menu 1 of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            delay 1
            set windowName to get name of window 1
            click UI element "Advanced" of toolbar 1 of window windowName
            click checkbox "Show Develop menu in menu bar" of group 1 of group 1 ¬
                of window "Advanced"
            click UI element 2 of window "Advanced"
            click menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
            click menu item "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events" of menu 1 of ¬
                menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
            delay 0.5
            if exists of UI element "Allow" of window 1 then
                click UI element "Allow" of window 1
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end enableJavascript
```

Comment: It should probably be noted that for this to work, **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** on the hidden **Developer** menu in **Safari** needs to be checked, which isn't by default.

Comment: @user3439894  I posted a solution to your comment as an edit to my original answer.  Curious as to what your thoughts are as to the second script in my post